# Is it possible to equip $\mathbb{R}$ with an order that is not linear?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The set of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ endowed with its standard order $\leq$ is a [linear ordered](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_order) set. Is there another ordering $\preceq$ on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $(\mathbb{R},\preceq)$ is NOT a linear ordered set?

Comment: You may find this interesting: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-order#Reals

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** The equality relation is a partial order.

---

Also, note that if $f\colon A\to B$ is a bijection, then every relation $R$ on $B$ can be pulled to an isomorphic relation on $A$ using: $S=\{(a_1,a_2)\in A\times A\mid (f(a_1),f(a_2))\in R\}$. So by taking any partially ordered set of cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ we can define the same order on the real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, indeed. For a non-trivial partial order, say that $0\preceq x$ for all $x\in\Bbb R,$ and for non-zero $x,y\in\Bbb R,$ say that $x\preceq y$ iff $|x|\le|y|$ and $xy>0$. (In effect, we're using the graph of $x\mapsto|x|$ as something of a [Hasse diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse_diagram) for the relation.)

Answer (score 1):

Here are a couple more.

1. Let $\preceq_2$ be the partial (but not linear) order defined on $\Bbb R^2$ by $\langle u,v\rangle\preceq_2\langle x,y\rangle$ if and only if $u\le x$ and $v\le y$. Let $h:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2$ be any bijection. For $x,y\in\Bbb R$ let $x\preceq y$ if and only if $h(x)\preceq_2 h(y)$; then $\langle\Bbb R,\preceq\rangle$ is isomorphic to the partial order $\langle\Bbb R^2,\preceq_2\rangle$, which is not linear.
2. For $x,y\in\Bbb R$ let $x\preceq y$ if and only if $\lfloor x\rfloor\le\lfloor y\rfloor$ and $x-\lfloor x\rfloor\le y-\lfloor y\rfloor$. In other words, $x\preceq y$ if and only if the integer part of $x$ is at most the integer part of $y$ **and** the fractional part of $x$ is at most the fractional part of $y$. This is a partial order, but it’s not linear: $\frac12\npreceq\frac43$, and $\frac43\npreceq\frac12$.